# Google Chrome Stop working with print();

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, pdf, iframe

I have a very basic HTML and that load a PDF in an iframe, the iFrame is hidden, so, before the last update for Google Chrome, everything was working fine and everything got mess up after the update.
What I do is simple, the code load a PDF dynamically and then after the file is been loaded in to the iFrame, a button shows that says "PRINT NOW" after you click that button, the print window shows and you print your doc. but now you click that button and nothing happen!!.
So I thought, well, maybe the Adobe Plugin needs an update, so I updated, so after that, the PDF do open to be print BUT! it shows a black page, yes just a black page, but if I lod the PDF directly is shows the information correctly... so I went back to use the built in reader.
To make it simple here is the HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-lg" onclick="printTrigger(\'iFramePdf\');" target="_blank" id="prints">
   PRINT NOW!
</a>

<iframe id="iFramePdf" name="iFramePdf" src="docs/docs.pdf" width="0" height="0" style="dispaly: none !important; width: 0; height: 0;"></iframe>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printTrigger(elementId) {
    var pdfRame = document.getElementById(elementId);
    pdfRame.focus();
    pdfRame.contentWindow.print();

    // window.frames["iFramePdf"].focus();
    // window.frames["iFramePdf"].print();

    var wnd = window.location.replace(\'index.php\');
        setTimeout(function() {
            wnd();
        }, 2);
}
</script>
```

And that is all for the button, iFrame and the script, like I said, a few months ago was working fine, nothing has changed except for the Google Chrome Update, if I install an old version it works again, but I can't be using an old version forever... so how can I fix this?... 
No error are show, the console shows that everything is fine... fireBug doesn't show any error either... I don't know what is wrong or how to update my code... 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.